# The table-border doesn't work in IE11 but works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to get the border working in IE11 like it's working in Google Chrome.
I use ASP.NET,inline styling, nth-child, last-child.
This is a example of how I use it.

```
.GridView tbody tr:nth-child(13) td,.GridView tbody tr:nth-child(15) td,.GridView tbody tr:last-child td{
        border-bottom:thin solid white;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me which attribute or selector I'm not allowed to use?
For example in IE it looks like that:

[image]

And in Chrome it looks like that(I'm sorry I'm not allowed to post the whole picture)

[image]

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net example (or use the snippet tool in the question editor), so we can see exactly what you mean

Comment: Also, *it doesn't work* - the single most unhelpful phrase you can use.  What isn't working? What is it not doing? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing? Help us to help you

Comment: Your screenshots look like it IS working in IE and not in Chrome. In the top screenshot, the borders are white.

Comment: @MrLister Sorry, I wasn't enough accurate because I meant the table-row  border for example.